# Browse through the files in android

Tags: android

I want to develop a code to browse the all folders and files in android emulator including sd card and internal memory storage. In Java there is JFileChooser available, in android how can i implement this functionality...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot browse all files in an Android device unless it is rooted. You need to have root privileges to access most of the file system (and you don't...).

Also, AFAIK there is no such API, but read [data storage section in the android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to see what you **can** do.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/42c92c01613beb8b?pli=1

i.e. As a widget not available , but you can use an app called OI File Manager and use its properties